# Mac OS X Finder: Substantial disparity between "Size" and "on disk" values for file

Tags: macos, finder

On Mac OS X (I'm using 10.8/Mountain Lion), you can inspect files in the Finder via Option-Click -> "Get Info". Doing so opens a panel with all sorts of information. In the top right corner, you can see the file size in MB. Next to "*Size*" (filed unter "*General*"), you get more detailed information: The size in bytes, as well as another size in MB *on disk*.

I noticed that some files have a substantial difference between their size in bytes/the value in the top right corner, and the *on disk* value. One example is the Clang binary:
[image: Size disparity in Finder]

Can anyone explain why there's such a huge difference (26.3MB vs. 10.9MB)? Are parts of the file shared (I have installed the Xcode command line tools, so the file exists in multiple locations)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

HFS+ compression!

The "Size" value represents the uncompressed size of the data in the file. The "on disk" value is how much storage is really needed for the compressed data. The [Mac OS X Hints site](https://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090902223042255) provides background on how this compression is implemented, and provides a link to the helpful [`hfsdebug`](https://web.archive.org/web/20210616020646/http://osxbook.com/software/hfsdebug/) tool that can be used to get information on compressed files.

Answer (score 1):

There are other explanation for this file size disparity as well! For example:

[image: screenshot of macOS finder showing a 1.23GB file taking up 2.6MB of space]

That's a 1.23GB file taking up 2.6MB on disk, which is clearly too much of a disparity for mere compression. My screenshot is of a [spare file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) representing a partial cache of a file accessible from a networked file system ([rclone mount](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/)). Essentially it's a virtual file that while appearing to be 1.23GB of space only actually contains 2.6MB of data. There are many other situations where a file's size and its on disk size might dramatically differ: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/418562/37817